# Add external login service not included in loginWith<service>

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth

I want to authenticate users using [battlenet](https://dev.battle.net/docs/read/oauth). This is not included in [Meteor.loginWithService](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice) and there is not a package on atmosphere to accomplish this.

I found [this example](https://github.com/Jabbslad/accounts-github). The library appears to refer to an older version of Meteor. I am using Meteor 1.0.32.

While I was able to change around the `Meteor.accounts` and other details, I cannot find the appropriate replacement to registering a new oauth service. When I try to use this function, the  callback is never invoked.

```
console.log("Want to now register a service");
Accounts.oauth.registerService('battlenet', 2, function(query) {
  console.log("Registering service now...");
```

I opened the console, and found that `Accounts.oauth.registerService` only takes a single argument of `name`.

What is the appropriate way to register a new external oauth provider in Meteor 1.0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution here its create a new `local package`.

Take a look into ehe [meteor-accounts-stripe](https://github.com/khamoud/meteor-accounts-stripe) its the best example over here, with that you get an idea of how to create a new `OAuth package` and maybe upload it into atmosphere maybe other people like you will need it on the future.

Comment: that helped a lot! For some reason, it seems like the `Accounts.oauth.registerService` is now on the client side