# Custom Meteor Accounts

Tags: meteor, package, meteor-accounts

I need to implement a new accounts package with trakt.tv service via OAuth2.
How can I use the source of accounts-facebook or other already implemented to create my own?

Answer (score 2):

This already has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861461/add-external-login-service-not-included-in-loginwithservice/28861602#28861602), in resume, you need to create a

```
local package
```

and take a look into the [meteor-accounts-stripe](https://github.com/khamoud/meteor-accounts-stripe) to get the idea about how to create a new `OAuth package`

Comment: I have troubles with _add package_ on the meteor app. I followed this [how to](https://atmospherejs.com/i/publishing) but I'm receiving errors from some files like _future.js_ and others related with _node modules_' directory. How can I test the packages just like a simple app? It's possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the [Meteor Packages](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages) at GitHub you can reverse engineer a solution.

Also see the [Accounts](https://www.meteor.com/accounts) project page at Meteor.